# How to encrypt sqllite database generated by greenDao with sqlchiper in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, greendao

I am using greenDao orm in my project for database operation . But I need to encrypt the data in database . I know that [sqlchiper](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) can encrypt sqllite database , but I can't integrate with greenDao . I have also viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196368/greendao-with-sqlcipher-integration-example) question followed the instruction , but it didn't work .

With greenDao , I can I can create database very simply

```
 DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "lease-db", null);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
```

I have replace the import "`import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;`" with this "`import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;`"

And followed sample code . Their sample code to create encrypted database is like this .

```
private static DevOpenHelper sDevOpenHelper;
    private static DaoMaster sDaoMaster;

    public static void init(Application app) {
        sDevOpenHelper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(app, DB_NAME, null);

        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(app.getApplicationContext());

        sDaoMaster = new DaoMaster(sDevOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase("secret-key"));
    }
```

Now what changes I need to be done to create encrypted database with green dao ?  [Here](http://pastebin.com/RqUkkvUy)  is my full code .

Comment: `"but can't get work with it"` which means?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: seems you don't want to get any answer, what does **"but it didn't work"** mean???