# Integrating SQLCipher with greenDAO

Tags: android, encryption, android-sqlite, greendao, sqlcipher

How to encrypt sqlite database in android with sqlchipher while using greenDao orm. I have searched this many time in SO , but didn't find any working solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your greendao generator module add this dependency

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-generator-encryption:2.2.0'
```

So the **build.gradle** file your generator module will look like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-generator-encryption:2.2.0'

}
```

And the in your app gradle file (**build.gradle** module app) add these dependencies and remove all other greendao related dependencies

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-encryption:2.2.2'
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.1'
```

and set up database like this way

```
  DaoMaster.EncryptedDevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.EncryptedDevOpenHelper(context, "secrets.db");
  Database database = helper.getWritableDatabase("your secret key");
  DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(database);
```

If there is any other option to do this , please share

Comment: i'm trying to read the data from daoSession but have 0 records.